# How do I fill certain percentage by height of an image using ImageMagick commands in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, imagemagick

I have an image with around 20% of its bottom filled with white color. But the image has some dots of other colors than white. I have 100s of such images which I would like to remove those dots from.

I have been using ImageMagick commands, and bash scripts to automate several tasks but I cannot find any command to fill certain percentage of an image from bottom by a solid color.

[image: I need to remove the dots marked by the arrow]

Comment: are all images of the same size?

Comment: No, they are of varying size.

Comment: I see you managed already?

Comment: Yes, I just did and posted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the goal by calculating the height, taking percentage (approximate) of the image's height and filling a white rectangle.

```
# A tool to fill up 10% of the bottom of given image
# by white color. Useful to remove unnecessary colors
# at the bottom of image.
# Usage: this_script.sh required_image.jpg

#!/bin/bash
image="$1"
right=$(identify -format %w "$image");
bottom=$(identify -format %h "$image");
top=$(expr $bottom \* 9 / 10 | bc);
left=0

convert "$image" -fill white -draw "rectangle ${left},${top},${right},${bottom}" "$image"
```

This can be automated for several images in a folder like:

```
for img in *.jpg; do bash <script.sh> "$img"; done
```